# How can i make Log4Net create a simple file.log, and rename it to file-dd-mm-yyyy.log at the start of a new date?

Tags: logging, sitecore, log4net, config, sitecore8

So i want todays logfile to be completely clear of all dateformatting in the filename so it would be easy to always find todays log file. But then i would like older logfiles to be renamed with a datestamp once a new day starts.

So the log folder would look something like this:

log.log                               *(<- todays logfile)*
log-16.02.2016.log
log-15.02.2016.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with the default file appender, you could using a [Rolling File Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender) though and roll them based on date. This will not take into account app restarts like the current appender does though.

Add a new appender and then update the root logger to use this one:

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
  <file value="logfile" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <priority value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

An alternative is to rename the file name format for the default file appender:

```
<file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/{date}.log.txt" />
```

This will allow you to sort (and group) the log files together more easily. You can find some more ideas in [this blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/cleanup-log-clutter-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to make staticLogFileName = false. I've been using this pattern successfully to generate files like myLogFilePrefix.20160124.log

```
<appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\Logs\\myLogFilePrefix" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.lo'g'" />
        <staticLogFileName value ="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger – %message%newline" />
        </layout>
</appender>
```

Alternatively you could use

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\Logs\\log-%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
```

but it will not rollover per day, only on start of application.